# Bluetooth works but hcitool doesn't

Tags: bluetooth, iwlwifi

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on an asus pn41 with intel celeron n5100.
Bluetooth works fine in fact I am using a Bluetooth mouse now but hcitool does not work.

When I run the command **sudo hcitool lescan** the response is:

```
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
```

When I run the command **sudo hcitool scan** response is:

```
scanning...
```

But it does not find anything.

---

Please help me, here is some useful information from my pc:
command **dmesg | grep Blue**:

```
gc@gc-server:~$ dmesg | grep Blue
[    2.974284] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.974314] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.974318] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.974320] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.974324] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.986863] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.1 build 0 week 30 2018
[    2.989834] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 2
[    2.989840] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    2.989841] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    2.989842] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    2.989843] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    2.989844] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    2.991259] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-0-1.sfi
[    4.013602] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.013606] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.013611] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.703382] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    4.703934] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1672528 usecs
[    4.703969] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[    4.719844] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 15518 usecs
[    4.720047] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-19-0-1.ddc
[    4.721867] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[    4.729076] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 121 week 36 2020
[    4.822259] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    4.822268] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    4.822275] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

command **hciconfig -a**:

```
gc@gc-server:~$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 64:6E:E0:9E:F4:8E  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:796685 acl:26326 sco:0 events:9415 errors:0
    TX bytes:776569 acl:97 sco:0 commands:3216 errors:0
    Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'gc-server'
    Class: 0x1c0104
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Desktop workstation
    HCI Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Revision: 0x100
    LMP Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Subversion: 0x100
    Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
```

command **bluetoothctl --version**:

```
gc@gc-server:~$ bluetoothctl --version
bluetoothctl: 5.53
```

Comment: Hello. I do not see the hcitool command that you used in the list of commands it uses. https://simpleit.rocks/linux/shell/connect-to-bluetooth-from-cli/ It also does not say to use sudo.

Comment: Output from my machine running Ubuntu 20.04.4 desktop. hcitool dev
Devices:
 hci0 00:1A:7D:DA:71:15

Comment: HI @David thanks for interest.
hcitool + **lescan** comand is used to find a low energy Bluetooth devices.